# Disable QDialogs default close button (upper left "cross button")?

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

Is it possible to disable/delete the QDialogs default close button at the upper left of the dialog?

Answer (score 11):

At least in (embedded) Linux, you can do this:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

With that, I get a window which has the title but no buttons.

Comment: This is the way. But don't forget to also handle the Escape key which closes the dialog (if your goal is to make it not dismissible by user).

Answer (score 3):

Clearing `WindowCloseButtonHint` in [`WindowFlags`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qt.html#WindowType-enum) may do what you want. Check out the example [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-windowflags.html).

Comment: I tried now to costumize the window by `setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint);` or `setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);` . Problem is, that both ideas still leave the maximize button and when maximized the close button appears again. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Use this function for your dialog

```
dlgLobLobLob->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::Desktop)
```

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it does not work - all buttons (close, maximize, minimize) are available. Guess it depends on the Unity Desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Try `setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint);` . You may want to check the [Window Flags Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-windowflags.html), and play around to see effects of all possible combinations of WindowFlags

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint)`

Comment: This is *very* similar to other answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25152802/10871073)), posted some years ago. Maybe you should add some explanation as to how/why it is better than any existing answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29988909)