# QProgressDialog without close button

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to remove the close button (see screenshot) of a `QProgressDialog`? I couldn't find anything useful in the docs/Google.

I use a modal `QProgressDialog` to show infinite process and block the GUI until a lengthy operation has completed. Because the GUI should be blocked, I don't want the user to be able to close the dialog.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the cancel button, or the system close button?

Comment: The system close button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965224/disable-qdialogs-default-close-button-upper-left-cross-button

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can hide close button of every window by clearing an appropriate flag:

#### With Qt 5.0

```
QProgressDialog dlg;
dlg.setWindowFlags(dlg.windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
```

> Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint 0x08000000  Adds a close button. On some platforms this implies Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint for it to work.

#### With earlier versions

```
    QProgressDialog dlg;
    dlg.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

where

- `Qt::Window` stands for window
- `Qt::WindowTitleHint` stands for displaying title on the top of the window
- `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` stands for not displaying buttons

Comment: Hm, it didn't work. May be it's because I use `QProgressDialog::exec()` to show the dialog?

Comment: @sashoalm, In windows, button stays visible, but you are unable to press it. You probably should also hide help button to make it invisible. I've tested it with `exec` also. What is your behavior like?

Comment: When I paste your code as-is, the close button stays and is not disabled. When I remove the flag for help button and close button, the help button disappears, but the close button stays (and is clickable).

Comment: @sashoalm, do you use Linux? May be your windows manager does not support this feature. You can try playing with flags. For example, this `dlg.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);` produces an window without buttons at all, and `Qt::Popup` produces windows without border.

Comment: No, I'm on Windows 7. Is it working on your computer? This worked for me - `dlg.setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint);`, from this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15656707/492336

Comment: @sashoalm, I found it works with Qt 5.0 but does not with Qt 4.8