# Disable X button in a QMainWindow

Tags: c++, linux, qt, raspbian

I have a QMainWindow window that shows a countdown for 10 seconds and will shutdown the system with `system("sudo shutdown -P");`. Of course I want to disable the "X", Max- and minimizer buttons from the title bar using `setWindowFlags()`.
I used `this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::CustomSizeWIndowHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint)` but unfortunately it is not working.

I Have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965224/disable-qdialogs-default-close-button-upper-left-cross-button), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699808/cant-add-minimize-button-to-qdialog-under-linux), [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/1812/remove-minimize-button-from-qdialog/8)
, [this](http://www.triait.com/answer/RE-setWindowFlagQtDialog-QtWindowStaysOnTopHint-not-working-on-Centos/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097323/setwindowflagsqtwindowstaysontophint-hides-qt-window) questions and also I ran the [windowflags-example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html) on my system and even this example did not work.
I have a Raspberry Pi 2, compile and run my code on Raspbian Jessie using Qt 4.8.

Can anybody help me?
thanks in advance!

Comment: If your WM doesn't understand Motif hints, Qt hints won't work. Try setting all these flags:CustomizeWindowHint|WindowTitleHint| WindowSystemMenuHint| WindowMinimizeButtonHint| WindowMaximizeButtonHint| WindowCloseButtonHint.

Comment: @Mogi Have you tried to give the flags to the QMainWindow constructor?

Comment: You can override closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event) and ingnore event, like this:

    `void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event)
    {
        event->ignore();
    }`

Comment: @AlexanderMedvidov Thanks, in this case it might work but for instance I have a Login page as well that must be closed after a successful login. in this case the `closeEvent()` is useless since i need to close the login page using `this->close();`.

Comment: @n.m. Hi and Thanks. How should I know if my Windows Manager (WM) understands the Motif hints? How can I set the flags?

Comment: @A.Sarid Hi & thanks. I am using these flags in the constructor of my `ShutdownClass`. I have a `HelperClass` which inherits from the `public QMainWindow` and all my other classes iherits from `HelperClass`. Now what do you mean and how? Sorry I didn't get your comment.

Comment: i suggest to set Qt::FramelessWindowHint to QMainWindow

Comment: @Mogi Maybe separate modal window with override closeEvent?)

Comment: @tty6 Hi, I have used that so absolutely it gives me a framelessWindow which is not preffered. I cannot change this flag afterwards!

Comment: @Mogi i suggest you to think about implementing your own custom min,max-close buttons with framelessWindowHint, besides you can use QWidget's setMask, this also can help