# Delete QDialogs default close button

Tags: linux, dialog, flags, qt4.8

I know, that's not a new question, but I didn't found the answer. I need a dialog with title, but without close button. And it should work on Linux with Qt 4.8.

I try to do it as here:
[Disable QDialogs default close button (upper left “cross button”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965224/disable-qdialogs-default-close-button-upper-left-cross-button) But it doesn't work for me. The title is with close button or there is no title at all.

The results from  [Window Flags Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Qt::Window` default flags:

```cpp
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```